# Characterisation of uniformly continuous function

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

I have the following exercise:
Let $(X,d)$, $(Y,e)$ be metric spaces.

This is the definition of distance of sets used in the exercise:

$d(A,B)=inf\{d(a,b)\colon a \in A, b \in B\}$

$d(f(A),f(B))=inf\{e(f(a),f(b))\colon f(a) \in A, f(b) \in B\}$

The exercise is:

Prove that $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ is uniformly continuous if and only if, for all non empty sets $A$,$B$ in $X$ such that $d(A,B)=0$ we always have that $d(f(A),f(B))=0$.

If we suppose that $f$ is uniformly continuous, the implication is easy. But the converse is very hard for me. Let me show you what I have tried:

Suppose that for all non empty sets $A$,$B$ in $X$ such that $d(A,B)=0$ we always have that $d(f(A),f(B))=0$, and for the sake of a contradiction suppose also that $f$ is not uniformly continuous.

Then there exist $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$, exist $x_\delta$, $y_\delta$ in $X$ such that $d(x_\delta, y_\delta)<\delta$ but $e(f(x),f(y)) \geq \epsilon_0$.

In particular, for all $\delta=\frac{1}{n}>0$ there exist $x_n,y_n$ in $X$ such that $d(x_n,y_n)<\frac{1}{n}$ but $e(f(x_n),f(y_n)) \geq \epsilon_0$

Then $A=\{x_n \colon n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $B=\{y_n \colon n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ are such that $d(A,B)=0$.

Then by hypotheses, we have that $d(f(A),f(B))=0$. Then, in particular for $\epsilon_0>0$, there exist $x_n,y_m$ in $X$ such that $e(f(x_n),f(y_m))<\epsilon_0$.

But I get a contradiction if $n=m$ but I don't know how to proceed in case that $n\neq m$.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $e$? Is that the metric on $Y$? If so, that doesn't seem to be in the statement you're trying to prove. Also, you may want to be explicit about how you've defined distances between sets.

Comment: What is $d(f(A),f(B))$? $d$ is a metric on $X$ but $f(A)$ and $f(B)$ are subsets of $Y$.

Comment: If you look very very very carefully, you will see a definition. If you can't, well, obviously you can't help me.

Comment: I've seen your definition. Indeed, I saw it before I posted the previous comment. I made my comment to suggest that your definition is incoherent.

Comment: The notation $d(A,B)$ is roughly as common as $\text{dist}(A,B)$, which is the other standard way of denoting this quantity.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to proceed in the case $m \not = n$. The sets $A,B$ you chose might satisfy $e(f(A),f(B)) = 0$.

Comment: But I don't know how to make a contradiction. $e(f(A),f(B))$ is an infimum, so it may happen that two elements are far away.

Comment: If $d(x_n,y_n) < \frac{1}{n+1}$, then we can take the pair $(x_{n+1},y_{n+1}) = (y_n,x_n)$, so that you will end up with $x_n \in A$ and $x_n \in B$, so that $e(f(A),f(B)) = 0$. I'm not sure how to solve this problem yet but we need to choose different sets $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I suspect this isn't true. The implication $d(A,B) = 0 \implies e(f(A),f(B))=0$ seems to be equivalent to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Cauchy_continuity) generalisation of Cauchy continuity, which implies only continuity but not uniform continuity. More specifically, I think $d(A,B) = 0 \implies e(f(A),f(B))=0$ holds for, say, $f(x)=e^x$, but I haven't carefully worked through all the steps of that argument.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I don't think it's true for $e^x$. Let $A = \{10^n : n \ge 1\}$ and $B = \{10^n+1/n : n \ge 1\}$. Then clearly, $d(A,B) = 0$. But $e(f(A),f(B)) \not = 0$ since $e^{10^n+1/n}-e^{10^n}$ goes to infinity, as can be verified on wolfram alpha.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I'm actually starting to think the result is true. It suffices to take $A$ and $B$ to each be sequences $(x_n)_n$ and $(y_n)_n$ with $d(x_n,y_n) < 1/n$. We want $e(f(x_n),f(y_m)) \ge \epsilon$ for all $n,m$. But we can find such counter example sequences if the function escapes to infinity or takes on the same values infinitely many times (think about $\sin^2(x)$). But if either of these two cases do not occur, I think the function will be uniformly continuous.

Comment: @mathworker21 I agree with everything you've just said, except perhaps the part where the result is true. It seems like this could be a form of continuity intermediate between uniform and classic (pointwise?) continuity. This conjecture seems to be supported by your observation (or at least, my interpretation of your observation) that we might need to impose additional assumptions to get uniform continuity.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist I realized I did make some assumption that $Y$ was $\mathbb{R}$, or a space where closed and bounded sets are compact. Because if $Y$ is such a space and neither of those two cases I mentioned above hold, then the function is uniformly continuous. I'm pretty sure what I said in my last comment will give a proof if $Y$ is such a space. But I agree with you that it seems that assumption is key.

Comment: @HeMan Is any of your spaces connected? If not, take $X=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$ with the usual metric and $f$  the characteristic function of the set $(1,2)$. I think it's easy to see that $f$ satisfies the property $d(A, B)=0\Rightarrow e(f(A), f(B))=0$. Since $(1,2)$ is clopen, $f$ is a continuous function, but  not uniformly continuous: Pick $x_n=1-\tfrac{1}{n}$ and $y_n=1+\tfrac{1}{n}$. Then $d(x_n,y_n)\rightarrow 0$, but $e(f(x_n),f(y_n))=1, \forall n$.  Both $X$ and $Y$ here are not connected. If this counterexample is correct, we should also try to find one on connected spaces (if possible).

Comment: @treedetective Your function isn't a counterexample: you already showed that function isn't uniformly continuous because it doesn't hold the condition.

Comment: are you sure that in $d(f(A),f(B))$, $f(a)$ is in $A$ ?

Comment: @Angel Indeed... That was a rookie mistake :)

Comment: The definition of $d(f(A),f(B))$ is still nonsensical. @HeMan, please edit.

Comment: To clarify, did you mean$$\operatorname{dist}(f(A), f(B)) = \inf\{e(f(a), f(b)) : a \in A, b \in B\}?$$

Comment: Yes, that the definition. Let me fix it.

Comment: It is interesting

Comment: Maybe I should clarify that the "d" for $d(A,B)$ is for distance, not for the metric d. Thats why I put $d(f(A),f(B))$ instead of $e(f(A),f(B))$

Comment: I was trying to fix my "proof", but I cannot. Moreover, I think the condition $d(A,B)=0\Rightarrow e(f(A),f(B))=0$ is strictly weaker than uniform continuity. In fact, for sequences we have that uniform continuity is equivalent to $d(x_n,y_n)\to 0\Rightarrow d(f(x_n),f(y_n))\to 0$. On the other hand, the condition given above states that, if $d(x_n,y_n)\to 0$, some sequence $d(f(x_{\alpha(n)}),f(y_{\beta(n)}))$ converges to $0$. There is not guarantee that $\alpha(n)=\beta(n)$ for all (even for almost all or for some subsequence of) $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: You are right, uniform continuity is equivalent to: "For every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that $\text{dist}(A, B)<\delta \Rightarrow \text{dist}(f(A),f(B))<\varepsilon$." This is definitely stronger than the condition we've been working with. But they could turn out to be equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $f$ is not uniformly continuous. Then there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ and two sequences $(x_n),(y_n)$ of elements of $X$ such that $d(x_n, y_n) < \frac 1 n$ and $e(f(x_n),f(y_n)) > \varepsilon$.

We need to define two sets $A$ and $B$ such that $d(A,B)=0$ (this is easy because $d(x_n,y_n) \to 0$), but with $e(f(A),f(B)) > 0$ and this is hard because for now we can only control $e(f(x_n),f(y_n))$ and not $e(f(x_n),f(y_m))$.

So a bit more work is required.

---

Suppose there is an $x_n$ (or a $y_n$) such that there are infinitely many $m$ with $e(f(x_n),f(x_m)) < \varepsilon/3$ or $e(f(x_n),f(y_m)) < \varepsilon/3$.

Then we can pick $A = \bigcup \{x_m \mid e(f(x_n),f(x_m)) < \varepsilon/3 \} \cup \bigcup \{y_m \mid e(f(x_n),f(y_m)) < \varepsilon/3 \}$
and $B = \bigcup \{y_m \mid e(f(x_n),f(x_m)) < \varepsilon/3 \} \cup \bigcup \{x_m \mid e(f(x_n),f(y_m)) < \varepsilon/3 \}$.

Then $d(A,B) = 0$ because we pick infinitely many pairs, and $e(f(A),f(B)) \ge \varepsilon/3$ because for example if we have $x_m \in A$ and $y_p \in B$ then $x_p \in A$ and so
$\varepsilon < e(f(x_p),f(y_p)) \\ 
\le e(f(x_p),f(x_n)) + e(f(x_n),f(x_m)) + e(f(x_m),f(y_p)) \\ 
< 2\varepsilon/3 + e(f(x_m),f(y_p))$
which means $e(f(x_m),f(y_p)) > \varepsilon - 2\varepsilon/3 = \varepsilon/3$

---

Suppose that for every $x_n$ (and $y_n$), there is only finitely many $m$ with $e(f(x_n),f(x_m)) < \varepsilon/3$ and $e(f(x_n),f(y_m)) < \varepsilon/3$.

Then we can recursively select a subsequence $(x_{\phi(n)})$ of $(x_n)$ such that $e(f(x_{\phi(n)}),f(y_{\phi(m)})) \ge \varepsilon/3$ for all $n,m$. At each step there is only finitely many indices that get disqualified, and since you start with an infinite sequence, there is always a way to continue the sequence.

Letting $A = \{x_{\phi(n)}\}$ and $B = \{y_{\phi(n)}\}$ you get $d(A,B) = 0$ and $e(f(A),f(B)) \ge \varepsilon/3$

---

In both cases we have found subsets $A,B$ with $d(A,B) = 0$ and $e(f(A),f(B)) > 0$.

Comment: The definition for the set $B$ looks a bit odd. $\{ \color{red}{y}_m \vert e \left( f(\color{red}{x}_n),f(\color{red}{x}_m) \right) < \varepsilon / 3 \}$? Similarly for the second part. Perhaps this doesn't matter for the proof, but writing it down this way strikes me as a little off.

Comment: you are absolutely right it is pretty weird. It's a mish-mash of two set-builder notations. I mean $\{y_m, m \in \{m \in \Bbb N \mid e(f(x_n),f(x_m)) < \varepsilon/3 \}\}$. Is it clearer this way ?

Comment: Aha. That is clearer.

Comment: Perhaps $\{ y_k \vert k \in C \}$ where $C = \{ m \in \mathbb N \vert e(f(x_n),f(x_m)) < \varepsilon / 3 \}$? That way you aren't using $m$ twice as a placeholder.