# An equivalence of uniform continuity in a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, uniform-continuity

Let $(E,d)$ and $(F,d')$ be metric spaces and consider $f:E\rightarrow F$. Prove that:

$f$ is uniformly continuous in $E$ $\iff$ for every  $A,B\subseteq E$ such that $d(A,B)=0$, it follows that $d'(f(A),f(B))=0$.

Where $d(A,B)=inf\{ d(x,y)|x\in A, y\in B\}$

The $\implies$ direction is easy from the definition but in the other direction I'm lost. Any help will be gratefully received.

Comment: This has an answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2062447/421069